# el significado de "vino sumido de la expedición"

Tags: significado

¿Cual es el significado de "[vino sumido de la expedición](https://www.wordreference.com/definicion/sumido)"?

Entiendo que "sumido" significa "enflaquecido/muy delgado" y "la expedición" significa "remisión/envío", pero no consigo entender el significado de la frase. ¿O quizás los términos los intepreto mal? Gracias.

Comment: Sería útil ver el contexto donde está esa expresión. ¿Podrías explicar de dónde proviene y editar la pregunta para incluir el párrafo donde aparece?

Comment: @pablodf76 La frase es un ejemplo de uso tomado de la definición enlazada de WordReference. No hay más contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La palabra "sumido" casi siempre va seguida de una frase preposicional formada por "en (algo negativo)": *sumido en llanto, sumido en la desesperación, sumido en la pobreza.*

Es muy raro -- si no incorrecto -- su uso como un adjetivo aislado.

Answer (score 1):

No interpretas bien, no.

**Expedición** en este contexto podemos suponer que significa de acuerdo con el [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HI3zxFT)

> 2. f. Excursión para realizar una empresa en punto distante

Imaginate los exploradores del siglo XIX en una **expedición** [excursión, viaje] para descubrir las fuentes del Nilo [empresa a un punto distante]. En un momento dado escasearon las provisiones, el alimento, y al **volver** estaban más **sumidos** [delgados] que cuando iniciaron el viaje.

> Livingstone **vino sumido de la expedición**

Comment: Yo diría: *Vino **consumido** de la expedición.*

Comment: @Gustavson Yo también. Desconocía ese significado de "sumido". El enlace cita el diccionario Espasa-Calpe. He pretendido explicar la frase completa partiendo de que ese significado sea correcto, ya que el OP tenía dudas respecto a "expedición" también.

Comment: Tu explicación es acertada. El problema radica en la oración de origen. El DRAE no recoge ese significado de "sumido". En la Web sólo encontré casos donde "sumido" (como "delgado") va seguido de la parte del cuerpo enflaquecida, por ej. "sumido de hombros", "sumido de mejillas", pero no encuentro "sumido" solo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus explicaciones!